# Keeping SSL connection active between reverse proxy and backend server

Tags: ssl, web-server, reverse-proxy, connection

I have a back-end server (Apache) that is too far from most of our users, so our idea is to implement a closer reverse proxy that will act as a cache.

At first glance it worked as a charm. The cached static files are served extremely fast, but for anything else, the reverse proxy (NGINX) needs to connect to the back-end server, which takes some time for the SSL handshaking, making these first requests slow.

I was searching for information on this but I couldn't find a way to keep this connection up. Is there a way for doing it?

I've even tried to learn more about websockets, but all implementations I could find were to answer an specific request, not to keep the connection intermediating the both web servers (NGINX at reverse proxy and Apache at back-end).

Does any of you have have any idea or tip about what to study/use/search in order to accomplish that?

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In nginx you can only specify [`keepalive`](https://nginx.org/r/keepalive) for an upstream connection if the connection is defined in an [`upstream`](https://nginx.org/r/upstream) block. For example:

```
upstream backend {
    server private-api.example.com:443;

    keepalive 32;
}
```

Here, `keepalive` specifies the maximum number of simultaneous open connections to the upstream server(s) per [worker process](https://nginx.org/r/worker_processes).

To use the upstream, you specify its name in your `proxy_pass` instead of the backend address.

For example, if you previously used:

```
     proxy_pass https://private-api.example.com:443;
```

You would change it to:

```
     proxy_pass https://backend;
```

Literally substitute the upstream's name for the defined `server`.

You must also set the HTTP version to 1.1 (because it rather absurdly defaults to 1.0) and clear the Connection header:

```
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
```

---

Keep in mind that there is also a `keepalive_timeout` you can define in the `upstream` which you may need to tune. By default it is 60 seconds, so if a connection is idle for that long it will be closed, even if there are fewer than `keepalive` connections open. The backend server will have its own keepalive timeout which you would also need to tune separately.

Comment: Thank you so much, Michael! It is working great now! :)